# Different key.serializer per producer when using transactions

Tags: spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm using spring-cloud-stream-kafka and I don't understand how is possible to change `key.serializer` property when using transactions. This is my configuration:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        accountSource:
          contentType: application/*+avro
          destination: account
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ${KAFKA_BOOTSTRAP_ADDRESSES}
          transaction:
            transaction-id-prefix: tx-
            producer:
              configuration:
                retries: 1
                acks: all                
        bindings:
          accountSource:
            producer:
              configuration:
                key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer # Ignored!
      schema:
        avro:
          subjectNamingStrategy: com.example.CustomSubjectNamingStrategy
      schemaRegistryClient:
        endpoint: ${KAFKA_SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL}
```

I read [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_kafka_binder_properties) that when setting transaction properties at binder level, all other specific binding producer properties. Does this mean all producers in the applications should use the same `key.serializer`? It seems very restrictive to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the transaction has to be started by the consumer binding (so it can send the offset to the transaction and commit or rollback after success/failure).

If there are multiple producer bindings, the consumer binding has no idea which one(s) the application will send data to, so we have to use one global producer.

One solution would be to write a custom delegating serializer and set a header in the output message to tell the serializer which delegate serializer to call.

Comment: We added delegating serializer/deserializers in 2.3 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/commit/4ac551d9454c386b1947c306f4360961a7106184#diff-1b82e52cf3793f92a5d4f2f71cc81273